# The module Map.Make is a functor, it cannot have any components

Tags: ocaml, functor

I want to have a Map datastructure for "env" in my lisp interpreter.

My code in env.mli is

```
module Env = Map.Make(String)

type t = (Ast.expression) Env.t

val empty: t

val add: string -> Ast.expression -> t -> t

val lookup: string -> t -> Ast.expression
```

But my code in env.ml is:

```
module Env = Map.Make(String)

type t = (Ast.expression) Env.t

let (empty: t) = Env.empty

let add (id: string) (value: Ast.expression) (env: t): t = Env.add id (value) env

let lookup (id: string) (env: t) : Ast.expression = Env.find id env
```

And there aren't any error prompt. Curious about why and how to modify my code.
Quite new to functors and maybe I didn't fully understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], the actual error message, where it occurs and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @glennsl I have added the context.

Comment: That's only enough context for people that have extensive experience writing lisp interpreters. I'm sure if you actually try you're able to describe the problem in more general terms.

Comment: If I try to evaluate your code as is, the error I get is `Syntax error: 'end' expected` on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the little information you provide, my guess is that what you want is to expose the `Env` fully as a map over strings. If so, you should replace

```
module Env = Map.Make(String)
```

with

```
module Env : Map.S with type key = string
```

but you could also leave the `key` type abstract:

```
module Env : Map.S
```

or expose only the type of the map:

```
module Env : sig 
  type 'a env

  type t = e env

  ...
end = struct 
  module Env = Map.Make(String) 

  type 'a env = 'a Env.t
      
  type t = Ast.expression Env.t

  ...
end
```

or you could make `t` itself abstract, to avoid referencing the env/map type at all:

```
module Env : sig 
  type t

  ...
end = struct 
  module Env = Map.Make(String) 

  type t = Ast.expression Env.t

  ...
end
```

There's many possible solutions depending on what you actually need it for.